# Wordpress , categories, archive and ACF

Tags: wordpress

on website i have lots of categories with products. I made for example CTP Tiles and then i made archive-tile.php to list all the products. Then i have single-tile.php where i target ACF to add some product images and description. How can i edit content of that master page of arhcive-tile.php ? Idea is to add some content and nice images to archive page.

When i make for example page called Tile (regular page) its not loading because its loading tile page from my CTP, how can i fix that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is so simple
You may use my plugin [ACF CPT Options Page](https://uk.wordpress.org/plugins/acf-cpt-options-pages/)

and [documentation is here](https://github.com/Tusko/ACF-CPT-Options-Pages#usage)